# Get mean value from 2D arrays and return the 2D array with indices of same values

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

This is the problem from CodeSignal (http://codesignal.com).

Question:

> You are given an array of arrays a. Your task is to group the
> arrays a[i] by their mean values, so that arrays with equal mean
> values are in the same group, and arrays with different mean values
> are in different groups.
>
> Each group should contain a set of indices (i, j, etc), such that the
> corresponding arrays (a[i], a[j], etc) all have the same mean. Return
> the set of groups as an array of arrays, where the indices within each
> group are sorted in ascending order, and the groups are sorted in
> ascending order of their minimum element.
>
> So if the input is: 
>  `a = [[3, 3, 4, 2], [4, 4], [4, 0, 3, 3], [2, 3], [3, 3, 3]]` 
>  The output should be: 
> `solution(a) = [[0, 4], [1], [2, 3]]`

Following is the code I did so far,

```
public static int[][] sortMean(int[][] a) {
    int[] means = new int[a.length]; //store means example: [3, 4, 2, 2, 3] 
    
    //get mean value from each array
    //store the values in mean array 
    for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        int sum = 0; 
        for (int j=0; j<a[i].length; j++) {
            sum += a[i][j]; 
            int mean = sum / a[i].length;
            means[i] = mean; 
        }
    }
    
    ArrayList<List<Integer>> groupList = new ArrayList<>(); 
    
    //arraylist to 2d-array
    int[][] b = groupList.stream().map(  u  ->  u.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray()  ).toArray(int[][]::new);
    return b; 
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to store the indices and values from the mean array to ArrayList.

I tried for loops and HashMap but it did not work.

Comment: "but it did not work" is really no good problem description. What exactly is the problem with your attempt? Any debugging information?

Comment: @MrSmith42 Thank you for your advice. I will add a more detailed explanation with debugging information if possible. To be brief(for loop approach), I used mean array to find the duplicate value and tried to store the same means value by creating a new ArrayList. However, I was not able to find a way to store indices of non-duplicated value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the streams API to group each array by the average value and convert it to a two dimensional array.

```
static int[][] sortMean(int[][] a) {
    return IntStream.range(0, a.length)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            i -> IntStream.of(a[i]).average().getAsDouble(),
            LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()))
        .values().stream()
        .map(list -> list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray())
        .toArray(int[][]::new);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] a =  {{3, 3, 4, 2}, {4, 4}, {4, 0, 3, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 3, 3}};
    int[][] output = sortMean(a);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(output));
}
```

output:

```
[[0, 4], [1], [2, 3]]
```